# Setting up JNI project for the first time -- is NDK required if I have NDT installed?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm starting a project where I will need to use JNI to allow Android to access embedded hardware peripherals.

I have Eclipse Juno installed and configured with the ADT and NDT.  I have imported an [existing application from github](https://github.com/hehopmajieh/modio_android) and I get an error when I try to build.  This project is pointing at the NDK folder on the project owner's filesystem.  I naively figured that this would be specified by the Eclipse environment, but apparently it isn't.

I thought that if the NDT was installed, that it automatically installed the NDK for me, but I haven't been able to find information about this.  I can go ahead and download the latest NDK and then change the project to point to my newly-downloded NDK's location, but don't want to do this if it is redundant.

Also, can someone point me to the place in the Project Properties tree that allows me to select the NDK location, so I don't have to manually modify the .cproject file?

Comment: I assume above where you say NDT you mean NDK?

Comment: by "NDT" I was referring to the module in Eclipse called the "Android Native Development Tools", which I now believe to not be a replacement or the same thing as the NDK.  Sorry for the noob question... should have just installed the NDK and tried it out before posting.

Comment: I believe you are referring to an eclipse plugin for development of NDK stuff. But yeah, that plugin requires you to install the NDK and point the plugin to your install I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably silly to ask this question without downloading and installing the NDK -- it's not like "installing" leaves artifacts and I could have just deleted the folder if it was not necessary.  I went ahead and installed r8e and replaced the reference in the .cproject file, and the project compiled okay.